# Nuxt - Dynamic route generation returns status 400

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt for my app and would like to have it connected to my server for data.

To generate dynamic routes I use the built-in generate method but I'm having some issues.

When the generate command is used it get this `ERROR  Request failed with status code 400` but when I visit the same URL it works fine.
Also, when I console log each individual route it shows up properly.

Code:

```
generate: {
    routes() {
        return axios.get('https://api-mcl.herokuapp.com/api/v1/companies').then(res => {
            return res.data.data.map(company => {
                return { route: `/companies/${company.slug}` }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: After some tweaking, I noticed that the routes are properly generated if I removed the asyncData function from the _id.vue component where the data should be. Will continue to work on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The issue was with the asyncData function in the component.

The function was like so:

```
async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    const { data } = await $axios.get(`/companies/${params.id}`)
    return { company: data.data }
```

but I should have used the payload like so:

```
async asyncData({ $axios, payload, params }) {
    if (payload) {
        return { company: payload }
    } else {
        const { data } = await $axios.get(`/companies/${params.id}`)
        return { company: data.data }
    }
}
```